# Javascript works in IE but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a textbox that requires a System-based mask.

FOLIO NUMBER      ###############??????????

When i tab into it, the TEXT is highlighted (Focus is set to True)

I have some Javascript that removes focus from the textbox when tabbed into, and changes the mode to overwrite mode (so to keep the mask while typing).  This works in IE 8, and IE 11, but not in Chrome.  I need something that works in both browsers.

Any suggestions.

Here is the Code snippet

```
function ChangePosition(element) {
            var range = element.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', 0);
            range.select();
            document.execCommand('OverWrite', false, true)
        }

        function ChangeBackPosition(element) {
            document.execCommand('OverWrite', false, false)
        }
```

Comment: Chrome doesn't support the "OverWrite" command. *edit* - and neither does Firefox. You can test with `document.queryCommandEnabled("OverWrite")`

Comment: so basically switching back and forth from overwrite to insert mode is not supported in Chrome or FireFox...great...any other options for overtyping to keep part of a mask.